# Use R CMD SHLIB to generate data from a .c file

Tags: r

I want to create a .dll from a .c file that should generate some data for further data analysis with the following code. rsnmm.c is saved in the current working directory.

```
system("R CMD SHLIB rsnmm.c")
```

However this does not work and I get the following error message

```
    In system(cmd) : 'make' not found
[1] 1
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: The recommended R instruction is `system2`, try `cmd <- "R";args <- c("CMD SHLIB", "rsnmm.c");system2(cmd, args = args)`. But I don't think this is the problem. What is your OS?

Comment: MY OS is Windows, after I used the approach suggested by @tpetzoldt I could run the initial code `system("R CMD SHLIB rsnmm.c")` succesfully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Windows, install the R Tools and set the system path, see

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

but if you use Linux, make also sure to have the compilers installed, see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ and select the instruction that matches your distribution.

Most Linuxes come with the compilers by default, except Ubuntu.